# Sigabart error in linphone lib for iPhone 4s (8.4.1)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, linphone, ios8.4

I have use linphone lib in on of my project. its working fine in my devices. but in client's iphone 4s with version 8.4.1 it is keep get crashing...

I found this crash log after symbolization

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib  vm_read_overwrite (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 260
1   libsystem_c.dylib   setipv4sourcefilter (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 389
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib  bitarray_set (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 123
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib  bitarray_zap (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 369
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib  szone_malloc_should_clear (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 3231
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib  0x00000001941d8ebb (in libsystem_malloc.dylib)
6   libsystem_malloc.dylib  0x00000001941d8da9 (in libsystem_malloc.dylib)
7   libsystem_malloc.dylib  szone_size (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 391
8   libsystem_c.dylib   qsort (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 71
9   linphone    belle_sip_strdup (in linphone) (belle_sip_utils.c:565)
10  linphone    belle_sip_header_set_name (in linphone) (belle_sip_headers_impl.c:36)
11  linphone    belle_sip_parameters_new (in linphone) (belle_sip_parameters.c:63)
12  linphone    belle_sip_uri_marshal (in linphone) (belle_sip_uri_impl.c:132)
13  linphone    belle_sip_object_marshal (in linphone) (belle_sip_object.c:508)
14  linphone    sal_address_as_string_uri_only (in linphone) (sal_address_impl.c:182)
15  linphone    +[FastAddressBook normalizeSipURI:] (in linphone) (FastAddressBook.m:136)
16  linphone    -[FastAddressBook loadData] (in linphone) (FastAddressBook.m:229)
17  linphone    __25-[FastAddressBook reload]_block_invoke (in linphone) (FastAddressBook.m:207)
18  AddressBook -[ABVCardParser peopleAndProperties:] (in AddressBook) + 111
19  libdispatch.dylib   0x00000001940692e3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
20  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_barrier_sync_slow (in libdispatch.dylib) + 305
21  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib) + 2247
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000194248db5 (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000194248b08 (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
```

can any one please guide me where this SIGABART is occurring or help for tracing this issue from above information. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure but it is likely that this may happen due to a specific contact in your client's address book. Which is not there in your device.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the location of your .xcodeproj? I got the same error when i changed the file index. If not it has something to do with your framework search paths. If thats the case then go into your build settings and change the framework paths to be $(SRCROOT)